# Automate Router Log In

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to allow a user to access a router's configuration page without knowing the credentials? The admin console for our router is a password protected web page, and I'd like to either store the credentials locally or automate his login.

Comment: What on earth are you talking about?

Comment: Give him the access details and then change them afterwards. Obfuscating the code won't help if his browser has to send the credentials to the target login form anyway.

Comment: @jahroy I have put on update on that should clear up any confusion.

Comment: Are you aware that the engineer will see the credentials anyway by simply viewing the page source? Are you aware that you can't overcome origin control with HTML and JS?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo The engineer is not tech savvy enough to know page source exists and how to do it. As for the second, I was not aware, just hopeful. I believe what I am after is obviously not possible, back to the drawing board, but many thanks to everyone for their time. I think maybe using curl and a hashed pass in the code may do it (ie a function decrypts the hash and stores true pass as a variable).

Comment: I bet there are some simple solutions to your problem... maybe if you cleaned up your question (by making it much shorter with a brief and specific statement of what you're after) and change the title (so it actually describes your problem) you'd get a better response. As it stands, this question is too long and confusing. It seems like you could explain exactly what you need in about 3 sentences max.

Comment: Example: _Is it possible to allow a user to access a router's configuration page without knowing the credentials? The admin console for our router is a password protected web page, and I'd like to either store the credentials locally or automate his login_.

Comment: No problem - Now I wish I had an answer for you!

Comment: @jahroy I have another question on the go for CURL 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118870/curl-http-post-login-and-redirect
But the router page populates with javascript and CURL cannot parse this. Another brick wall. I will post a solution when I find one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Greasemonkey (userscript) to automate login page (automatically fill in credentials and click login button).

Comment: This answer was not the exact route I took, but it certainly lead me there. I tested Tampermonkey (chrome's version of Greasemonkey) and it reminded of some small work I did with chrome extensions. Two files later totalling of 30 lines and job done. Many thanks this made the penny drop!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your router.

1/ Create a new account with limited rights directly in your routers config

2/ Use a 'proxy' page. If authentication (HTTP, cookie, headers, etc.) is needed, you have to emulate a session (curl is a powerfull and complete HTTP lib).

```
BROWSER -> | cgi script (authentication)        |
           | start HTTP session                 |-> login -> ROUTER
           | (your proxy knows the credentials) |<- authentified <-
           |                                    |-> config page ->
           |                                    |<- form (url, field) <-
           |                                    |-> form url, field values ->
result  <- | get result and print it            |<- result <-
           | end HTTP session                   |
```

You can define your requests params after an observation of a complete session with a proxy (fiddler ...) or your browser's debugger

Answer (score 0):

Use the browser's password manager like this in Firefox:

[image: Firefox preferences]