# Curl HTTP Post Login and Redirect

Tags: php, redirect, cookies, curl

I am trying to create a page to log in to a local router automatically. I am using CURL currently to log in to the page and authenticate. This part of the the code appears to be working correctly. The issue I am having is that once CURL has authenticated, I need to then redirect the user to this page so that they can navigate, however, I will also need to use the cookies collected by CURL.

Here is my code as it stands at the moment

```
$data = array(
'username' => 'admin',
'password' => 'admin',
);
$ch = @curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://192.168.69.1:65080/login.cgi');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Expect:'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'public_html/cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'public_html/cookie.txt');

$result = curl_exec ($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close ($ch); 

print_r($result);
print_r($info);


//Working until this point
preg_match('/^Set-Cookie:\s*([^;]*)/mi', $result, $m);
parse_str($m[1], $cookies);

foreach($cookies as $key=>$cookie)
{
     setcookie($key, $cookie, time() + 60*60*24*30, '/');
}

header("location:".$info['redirect_url']);
```

As you can see I found a snippet to loop through the `$result` info and then set them as cookies before redirecting, however, this is not working correctly and I am redirected to the login page not the index page.

If I do a further call before I close CURL, using the redirect url as the url, I do get a partial print of the index page, however, the important images etc are not displayed. But I need to be able to access the page and navigate rather than simply printing the page.

Here is a print of `$result`

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: /index.cgi
Set-cookie: show_security_warning=deleted; expires=Sunday, 09-Jun-13 10:54:00 GMT
Set-cookie: ui_language=en_US; expires=Tuesday, 19-Jan-38 03:14:07 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Mon, 09 Jun 2014 10:54:01 GMT
Server: lighttpd/1.4.31
```

Here is a print of `$info`

```
Array
(
    [url] => http://192.168.69.1:65080/login.cgi
    [content_type] => text/html
    [http_code] => 302
    [header_size] => 314
    [request_size] => 251
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.484
    [namelookup_time] => 0
    [connect_time] => 0
    [pretransfer_time] => 0
    [size_upload] => 255
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 526
    [download_content_length] => -1
    [upload_content_length] => 255
    [starttransfer_time] => 0
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [redirect_url] => http://192.168.69.1:65080/index.cgi
)
```

Here is my cookie.txt

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

192.168.69.1    FALSE   /   FALSE   0   AIROS_SESSIONID d19e097a07b7b76fd7d90267a8e1f4d2
192.168.69.1    FALSE   /   FALSE   1370775278  show_security_warning   deleted
192.168.69.1    FALSE   /   FALSE   2147483647  ui_language en_US
```

Finally here is a print of `$cookies`

```
Array
(
    [show_security_warning] => deleted
)
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction of how to achieve the next step, I would be most grateful.

Comment: I am still strugling with the above, however, if I add this line `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` then it does return the page with all the fields and the information necessary ie status etc. However, none of them have any values as the page is populated with javascript. CURL cannot parse this, therefore I am looking at something similar to phantom.js, but I am not hopeful. I would still like to know how I am able to use the cookies collected by CURL. But it seems these cookies are for 127.0.0.1 and not the router IP which I believe to be another issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your strategy will ever be sucessfull.

Curl is working as a web client. It means Curl and your web browser are probably seen as distinct hosts by the router.

```
[CLIENT (WEB BROWSER)] ---HTTP---> [PHP WEBSERVER]
                                   [CURL] ---HTTP---> [ROUTER (WEBSERVER)]
```

PHP has a particular behaviour : it stores sessions in files whose name depends on the session id cookie value only, so it is (or was ... I dont know all versions of PHP) possible to steal a session by capturing the session cookie / cloning the cookie values.

Not all CGI libs are doing the same. I believe your router has a safer session storage method, as it should be expected from a security dedicated device (for example
 a key based on the client IP and the session cookie value).
In this case your method is useless.

You'd better to use a javascript based form (in order to post the id/password) and maybe an iframe requesting the router login page before (in order to initialize the routers cookie values). Using a javascript form will show the credentials to your user which is probably not what you want

Comment: I feared this may be the case. I did look at Javascript iframe and form submit but I had issues with cross domain etc. If you have a solution in mind I have another question on the go for this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076855/automate-router-log-in

Comment: Well only you answered so you don't have much competition for the bounty. Many thanks for your help I eventually was able to solve my issue by creating a chrome extension. But like you said, I have moved no further forward using CURL.